# How to upload different images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I succeeded in displaying an image in a widget inside a container using **image_picker**. I want them all to look different when different images are selected inside the 1st, 2nd and 3rd containers. However, if you upload only one image, all the images inside the container will be the same.

Of course, you vaguely know that you can upload an image using multiple `_image` variables, but can't you post it with a cleaner code?

I am **NOT** asking the use of **multiple_image_picker**. I hope you understand what I mean.

This is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../../constants.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class UploadFishingVesselImages extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadFishingVesselImages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UploadFishingVesselImages> createState() =>
      _UploadFishingVesselImagesState();
}

class _UploadFishingVesselImagesState extends State<UploadFishingVesselImages> {
  var _image;
  final _picker = ImagePicker();

  Future choiceImage() async {
    var pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = pickedImage;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: baseColor10,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          color: baseColor50,
        ),
        title: Text(
          '선박판매등록',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: baseColor50,
            fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
            fontSize: titleMedium,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  TopBar(context),
                  marginHeight32,
                  buildTextColumn(),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {
                            await choiceImage();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            height: 90,
                            width: MediaQuery
                                .of(context)
                                .size
                                .width * 0.3,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: baseColor20,
                            ),
                            child: _image == null
                                ? Container()
                                : Image.file(File(_image.path)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {
                            await choiceImage();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            height: 90,
                            width: MediaQuery
                                .of(context)
                                .size
                                .width * 0.3,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: baseColor20,
                            ),
                            child: _image == null
                                ? Container()
                                : Image.file(File(_image.path)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {
                            await choiceImage();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            height: 90,
                            width: MediaQuery
                                .of(context)
                                .size
                                .width * 0.3,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: baseColor20,
                            ),
                            child: _image == null
                                ? Container()
                                : Image.file(File(_image.path)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  // Error occurs. 'The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned
                  // to the parameter type 'File'.
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Visibility(
        visible: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .viewInsets
            .bottom == 0,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: primaryColor50,
          foregroundColor: baseColor10,
          focusColor: primaryColor50,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

// 상단 텍스트
  Column buildTextColumn() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          '사진 등록',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: baseColor50,
            fontSize: titleMedium,
            fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
          ),
        ),
        marginHeight4,
        Text(
          '판매선박의 사진을 등록해주세요.(최대 20장)'
              '\n다양하고 선명한 사진을 올릴 경우, 판매 확률이 더욱 높아집니다.',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: bodySmall,
          ),
        ),
        marginHeight32,
      ],
    );
  }

// 상단바
  Column TopBar(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 3,
                color: baseColor30,
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width * 0.2,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 3,
                color: baseColor30,
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width * 0.2,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 3,
                color: baseColor30,
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width * 0.2,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 3,
                color: primaryColor50,
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width * 0.2,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 3,
                color: baseColor30,
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width * 0.2,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        marginHeight4,
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '선박정보',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'medium',
                      fontSize: labelSmall,
                      color: baseColor30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '옵션',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'medium',
                      fontSize: labelSmall,
                      color: baseColor30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '설명등록',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'medium',
                      fontSize: labelSmall,
                      color: baseColor30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '사진등록',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'medium',
                      fontSize: labelSmall,
                      color: primaryColor50,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '결제',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'medium',
                      fontSize: labelSmall,
                      color: baseColor30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: browsed simulator]

Comment: can you explain the issue? I tried but not able to understand it properly.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your comment. If I select the image in iOS simulator, same images are shown in the 3 containers. I want to show different images at the each containers.